# Error: Protocol error (IO.close): Target closed - while generating pdf with promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to generate multiple files to pdf using **"html-pdf-node"** package using Array.map() function then resolve all async processes with Promise.all(). But the problem is that after generating some files it give **Protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Target closed**. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

below is my code

```
async function generatePDFs(result) {
        const filename = [];
      
        const generatePdfPromiseArray = result.map(async (item) => {
          const file_name = getRandomFileName();
          const html = "abc";
      
          const margin = {
            top: "210px",
            right: "100px",
            bottom: "150px",
            left: "80px",
          };
      
          const options = {
            format: "A4",
            path: `some/path/${file_name}.pdf`,
            margin: margin,
          };
      
          try {
            const pdfBuffer = await html_to_pdf.generatePdf({ content: html }, options);
            await fs.writeFileSync(options.path, pdfBuffer);
            filename.push(file_name);
            console.log("PDF saved successfully!");
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error generating PDF:", error);
          }
        });
      
        // Wait for all the promises to resolve
        await Promise.all(generatePdfPromiseArray);
      
        return filename;
      }
```

In here I have used result.map() to create array of promises which will generate the PDFs. Then, we use Promise.all() to wait for all these items. But still getting Target Closed error

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2735